# I'm installing 16.04 2 on a laptop with intel celeron m, 1.3ghz/1.24 gb used forcepae and noapic

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I'm installing 16.04 2 on a laptop with intel celeron m, 1.3ghz/1.24 gb used `forcepae -- forcepae` and `noapic`

[image]

Please look at picture... it ends installation by removing dvd... now what?

Comment: You forgot the picture... But if it tells you to remove the installation disk and reboot, just do that.

Comment: Yes sorry, i'll post the question again with picture but i only can post a question once every 20 min..than the laptop starts using windows xp again...

Comment: I would guess that you are using or otherwise suggest that you should use an *'Ubuntu family flavour' with a light desktop environment:* Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu (and not standard Ubuntu) in a computer with intel celeron m, 1.3ghz/1.24 gb.

Comment: Try to *edit* your original question (instead of posting a new question).

Comment: oke, which one would you suggest (most likely to succeed)?

Comment: Lubuntu has an ultra light desktop environment, LXDE. Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu have medium light desktop environments, MATE and XFCE. Try them and use the one you like best.

Comment: I did, but couldn't find the way to post post the pic..

Comment: In the AskUbuntu editor: Click on the image icon (a rectangular box with a landscape), and a target box is popping up. Then drag and drop an image file from the file browser to the target box.

Comment: Oke, thanks sudodus! Meanwhile i've posted this question again with the picture...